# Cant Access Phpmyadmin on Ubuntu LTS 22.04 (HTTP Error Code 500)

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx, phpmyadmin

I just installed `phpmyadmin` on my PC. I followed several instructions such as:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/your_domain/phpmyadmin
```

I use NGINX as the webserver and PHP version 7.4. Previously, I had tried to install several additional PHP modules such as `php-curl`, `php-mbstring`, `php-json`.

But it still displays the HTTP error 500 error.

Did I miss an installation step or miss some module so that `phpmyadmin` can't be accessed?

Comment: Have you looked at the nginx error logs?

Comment: also, honest remark: MySQL brings its own "MySQL Workbench" (GPLv2) these days, phpmyadmin isn't usually what you want anymore.

Comment: PHP 7.4 has reached end of life and is no longer receiving updates, consider upgrading to 8.1.